# Password field with validation and "Show password" option in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I'm trying to make an password field, that matches the following criteria:

1. Valid password should be from 6 to 24 symbols long, and have at least one digit.
2. When the field contains invalid password, it should always be have .ng-invalid class.

To make password symbols visible I use two inputs synchronized through model:

```
<form name="form" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller" novalidate>    
<label>
   Password:
    <input type="password" name="uPass" maxlength="24" ng-hide="formFlags.showpass" ng-model="user.pass" ng-required validate-pass />   
    <input type="text" name="uPass" maxlength="24" ng-show="formFlags.showpass" ng-model="user.pass" ng-required validate-pass />
    <span class="message" ng-show="form.uPass.$dirty && form.uPass.$invalid">Must be from 6 to 24 symbols long ang contain at least one digit.</span> 
</label>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="uShowPass" ng-model="formFlags.showpass" toggle-pass/>Show password
</label>    
</form>
```

See full code here: [http://jsfiddle.net/adept/9uCGQ/44/](http://jsfiddle.net/adept/9uCGQ/4/) .

Here I'm trying to do the following:

1. I enter an invalid password. The input field gets.ng-invalid class
   (red border).
2. I click "Show password". Password input  gets
       hidden, text input gets visible.

The problem is that  is not validated until I change it's value. How do I make it validate immediately after it is shown?

**UPD:** in AngularJS of versions 1.2.x and higher my example works properly, the issue is relevant only for lower versions.

Comment: One thing to note is that the name of an input needs to be unique if you want to use it for field validation otherwise it will overwrite. You need to rename uPass for the text field and reference both of them in form.uPass.$dirty && form.uPass.$invalid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add formatters.unshift too, so it will also look to model changes, not only view ones.

Edited fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9uCGQ/5/

Added code:

```
       ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(viewValue) {
            if (viewValue.length >= scope.formFlags.minpasslength && PASS_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                // it is valid
                ctrl.$setValidity('pass', true);
            } else {
                // it is invalid
                ctrl.$setValidity('pass', false);
            } 
            // update model anyway to sync password fields
            return viewValue;
        });
```

More about the two properties (parsers and formatters) on the ng-controller documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: Thank you, your answer was quite useful to me.